How to Design a Space-Efficient Upload Component for Multiple Document Types with Click and Drag-and-Drop Options?
I'm working on a form that requires users to upload multiple documents of different types. Currently, our upload component is taking up a lot of space, and I'm looking for suggestions on how to design a more space-efficient version. The component needs to support both click-to-upload and drag-and-drop functionality, and there should be multiple upload areas to accommodate different document types.
What are some best practices or design patterns for incorporating an upload feature that balances functionality, handles different document types, and saves space? How can I streamline the experience for users when they need to upload several documents without cluttering the form layout? Any examples or insights would be appreciated!

Once I worked for an EA that needed to upload files to a data lake and that information should be validated before upload it because it included an OCR system that gathered information and passed it to a database.
So I remember that my solution included a table as a previous step and listed all the files ready to submit. You can add or remove fields to the table but I believe that the principle is the same.

